# ORDER BY custom field value out of where clause

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, order, sort

Based on example here https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

I'd like to modify the query

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'state_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'state',
        'value' => 'Wisconsin',
    ),
    'city_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ), 
),
'orderby' => 'city_clause') );
```

to be able to get all posts where `state` is 'Wisconsin' OR `state` is 'California' and ORDER BY `population` DESC.

I'm failing in writing such query in WP.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define that a population has to be set, and make a list of allowed states as an array.

Afterwards, take population into the `orderby` and sort it `DESC`.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => array( 'Wisconsin', 'California' ), //allowed values
            'compare' => 'IN' // state must be in array above
        ),
        'population_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'population',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'population_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

To have two different condition combined with an `OR`:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => array( 'Wisconsin' ), // allowed values
            'compare' => 'IN' // state must be in array above
        ),
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'timezone',
            'value' => 'central',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        'population_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'population',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'population_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Thanks @fischi - could I kindly ask u for a tip on yet another modification to this query: what if I need to get all posts WHERE `state` is 'Wisconsin' OR `timezone` is 'central' ORDER BY `population` DESC

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thanks @fischi - but I have two problems with that solution: 1) the value of 'state_clause' in meta_query array gets overwritten - so only last declaration stays ('timezone') if u actually dump the query. 2)  the 'relation' => 'OR' ruins the logic of a query - now result is all posts in DB as population exists in all cases